# Как узнать с какого IP адреса и когда было обращение к БД

Tags: postgresql

Мне необходимо узнать было ли обращение к БД с определенного IP.В каком лог файле( если таковой имеется ) хранится информация об истории обращений к БД Postgresql 9.5? База установлена на Windows 7 Professional. Возможно ли как то это наблюдать через PgAdmin III?

Answer (score 0):

Должна быть включена [настройка](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-logging.html)

```
log_connections = on
```

Тогда в логе СУБД будет фиксироваться подключение к базе. Затем любым удобным способом ищите в логе информацию о подключении с нужного хоста.

По-умолчанию эта настройка выключена.

Где сам лог - вопрос отдельный. При включенном `logging_collector` (одноимённая настройка) лог СУБД будет писаться в директорию указанную в настройке `log_directory`